# NHibernate ClassMap get column name for property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have ClassMap and entity. In code I would like to get column names for properties in entity. Any Idea?

```
public class AccountToDepotMap : ClassMap<AccountToDepot>
{
    public AccountToDepotMap()
    {
        Table("COPS_WPA_ACCOUNT_DEPOT");
        Id(t => t.RecId, "REC_ID");
        Map(t => t.RecordDate, "REC_DATE");
        Map(t => t.DepotId, "WPA_DEPOT_ID");
        Map(t => t.AccountId, "WPA_ACCOUNT_ID");
        Map(t => t.IsActive, "ISACTIVE").CustomType<YesNoType>();
    }
}

public class AccountToDepot
{
    public virtual long RecId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string DepotId { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to ask on property `DepotId` and result will be `WPA_DEPOT_ID`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an deep overview:

[Exploring nhibernate mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25579422/1679310)

And the simple code snippet from here

[How do you get the database column name out of an auditing event listener in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24153314/1679310)

how to get the a persister:

```
var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
var factory = ... // Get your ISessionFactory
var persister = factory.GetClassMetadata(entityType) as AbstractEntityPersister;
```

which can be later iterated

```
// the set of Properties
var propertyNameList = persister.PropertyNames;

// here we get all the settings for remaining mapped properties
foreach (var propertyName in propertyNameList)
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

using above code

This is working in my case

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < persister.PropertyNames.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (persister.GetPropertyColumnNames(i).Count() > 0)
            {
                columns.Add(persister.GetPropertyColumnNames(i).ToList().First());
            }
        }
```